# How to convert a week number with year into datetime format in python pandas?

Tags: python, regex, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe `df`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,2,3,4,5], 
               'week': [201613, 201714, 201715, 201716, 201717]})
```

which looks like:

```
   id    week
0   1  201613
1   2  201714
2   3  201715
3   4  201716
4   5  201717
```

The week column is telling the week of a particular year. For example `201613` means 13th week of 2016.

I wish to add a new column `week_timestamp` which should give me the time stamp of monday this week. it should give me something like `2016–03–28 00:00:00`for `201613`.

How can I do this in pandas?

Comment: Hint: you can do this from first principles without much overhead. Think of an algorithm to get from week number to date using basic operations (i.e. `+` and `*`). First write it out in words, then write it in logic / Mathematics, then have a go at implementing it in Python.

Comment: I tried `df['week_timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['week'] + '1', format='%Y%W%w')
` but it gives me an error: `TypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('<U21') dtype('<U21') dtype('<U21')`

Comment: df['week'] is an int, try df['week'].astype(str) to use it as string

Comment: This should solve your problem `pd.to_datetime(df['week'].astype(str) + '1', format="%Y%W%w")`

Comment: I remember I had to do this in excel about 10-11 months ago (before I started python), just google how to convert week number into a date and you can convert the math into Python code. if Erfan's solution doesn't work let me know and i'll  have a crack.

Answer (score -3):

df['week_timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['week'].astype(str) + '1', format='%Y%W%w')

Comment: If [@Erfan's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56102886/how-to-convert-a-week-number-with-year-into-datetime-format-in-python-pandas#comment98840407_56102886) works for you let the user know so that they could post an answer.